# mysql Copy table from server A to server B using sh

Tags: mysql, sh, sqlyog

Right now I use sqlyog to copy table from server A to server B with no problem.

```
+----------+      +----------+
| Server A |      | Server B |
+----------+      +----------+
| table1   |      | tablexx  |
| table2   | =>   | table2   |
+----------+      +----------+
```

I want to copy from serverA table2 to server B table2 with same structure.
I have already use mysqldump but it's look I do not have permission on server B.

If I do that from sqlyog there is no error.

Comment: [user@host]$  mysqldump -hip.server.2  -uusername -ppassword db1.table2 > dump.sql --- i have try this

Answer (score 0):

sorry , this question solved .

```
[user@host]$  mysqldump -hip.server.2  -uusername -ppassword db1.table2 > dump.sql
```

the correct one is

```
[user@host]$  mysqldump -hip.server.2  -uusername -ppassword db1 table2 > dump.sql
```